# Error: ModelAssociationDone@../../components/sync/driver/model_association_manager.cc:378, datatype error was encountered: Association timed out

Tags: performance, google-chrome, autocomplete, passwords, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Chrome (55.0.2883.87 (64 bit)) on Ubuntu (16.04 (64 bit)) and am having problem using the autocomplete with passwords.

To start off with I was having a delay with the password autocomplete (goto one of my favourite websites with a login page and chrome will take 3-10 seconds to enter username and password automatically). I looked around on the net and there is some mention that a corrupt profile might cause this.

So - disconnected profile (under Chrome > Settings). And have now re-connected my profile.

Now I cannot get any passwords at all!

I check https://passwords.google.com/settings/passwords and I can see them there.

If I check chrome://sync/ I see the following error under the
Passwords, Autofill Profiles, Autofill Wallet and Autofill Wallet Metadata entries:

> Error: ModelAssociationDone@../../components/sync/driver/model_association_manager.cc:378, datatype error was encountered: Association timed out.  0   0

I have tried removing my profile again and restarting but this has not helped. Looks like my password manager in chrome is poked.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Cheers,
Gareth

Update - Since posting this the passwords are now populating ok however they are taking around 7 seconds to autocomplete (just started magically happening again). I still see the same error in sync internals.

Comment: Exact same behavior here.